# Loosing Styles After Reloading Angular App

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

The App works fines but when the user clicks in the refresh button some of the material styles breaks. How do I correct this error?

[image]

[image]

Additional Information: Working with angular 10 and Firebase. The app uses lazy modules, I think this has some relation with the problem, since it only breaks inside another routing module than no the main one.

Some Code:

Styles.css

```css
@import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
    
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  margin: 0;
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./components/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
  { path: 'redefinir-senha', component:RedefinirSenhaComponent },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./components/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule), 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent}
];
    
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
})
```

home-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent, children: [
      { path: 'mudar-senha', component: RedefinicaoDeSenhaComponent },
      { path: 'relatorio', loadChildren: () => import('../relatorio/relatorio.module').then(m => m.RelatorioModule) },
      { path: 'pesquisa-relatorio', loadChildren: () => import('../pesquisa-relatorio/pesquisa-relatorio.module').then(m => m.PesquisaRelatorioModule) },
      { path: 'pesquisa-viagens', loadChildren: () => import('../pesquisa-viagens/pesquisa-viagens.module').then(m => m.PesquisaViagensModule) },
      { path: 'dados-de-viagem', loadChildren: () => import('../dados-de-viagem/dados-de-viagem.module').then(m => m.DadosDeViagemModule) },
      { path: 'configuracoes', loadChildren: () => import('../configuracoes/configuracoes.module').then(m => m.ConfiguracoesModule), 
      canActivate: [AdminGuard] }
    ],
  }
]; 
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

Comment: Looks like the material icons module isn’t loaded in the second screen shot. Guessing it’s loaded in another module but not this one

Comment: are you registring icons in some modules and not in another?. I think that you should register only in the main module but I'm not pretty sure

Comment: It´s placed only in the styles.css, which is loaded by angular.json. I think the problem happens because I am working with lazy loading and that one is another module. If I refresh the components of the main module it works fine. When I am testing with the local host it works for all modules. Another relevant information is that others components of angular material are not working as the print shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing the options source map and css extract in angular.json production configuration. I don't know which one is the right yet.